# SSRS data driven subscription and parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I'm trying to test setting up a data driven subscription that takes a parameter from the report but it wont validate the query, should I be able to do this.

SP: Select * from Table where Column = @Variable

The @Variable is called the same of the report.

This is 2017 version of reporting services

Comment: You are referring to the query in the subscription, not the report, correct? This query does not allow parameters because it is meant to run on a schedule without interaction from a user.

Comment: ah ok thanks, I was hoping to pass a variable in instead of having to code it in and wasn't sure if there was a setting I was missing or a permission I needed to apply to use parameters.

Comment: No problem, I moved it to an answer since it addressed your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription query does not allow parameters because it is meant to run on a schedule without interaction from a user.